# how to call a workbook without knowing the name vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a folder with a lot of excel sheets each named of the customers name and i have another workbook with code  with a folder picker to go through the workbooks in the folder and run specific code to each sheet but i m stuck because i cant seem to call the workbooks beforehand because i don't know the name of the workbook

Comment: add your code to the post

Comment: If you're going through the workbooks in a folder, then just assign that workbook to a variable and use that. `Dim wb as Workbook`, and you can get the name if you really need it with `wb.Name`.